# C++ incrementing in IF condition

Tags: c++

I was solving some exercises for school which I have to find the output of a program and I came up to this,

```
 int c=3;
if((1==1)||(c++==4)&&(1==1))
{
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Why didn't it output 4, as c++ should be incremented after the line was executed?

Comment: Try to run it in a debugger. Also: No effort, -1.

Comment: Please do not do this. Do one thing at a time. Makes the code easy to read/maintain. Will avoid you having to ask this sort of question!. If you do not understand if just after writing the code, try figuring it out in a years time

Comment: My guess is since you have `||` operator and first expression is evaluated to `true` than the rest of expressions won't be executed at all

Comment: @EdHeal This is a problem solving question we take in school for further understanding of computer logic, I did not write this program.

Comment: Please take heed to my comment. Do not write code like this

Comment: @user202729 I did try to run it in a debugger before I post the question, not everyone is a genius like yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and have a look at this

```
int main()
{
    int c=3;
    if(((c++==4)&&(1==1)) || (1==1))
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
}
```